# RUBY ON RAILS PRODUCTION environment, CANNOT CLEAR CACHE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, cache-expiration

Is there a way to clear cache in **production environment**

using the default cache of rails

I tried using `caches_action :index, :expires_in => 1.minute`
but it only works on development environment but not in production

Comment: u have to wtire this at the environments/production.rb

Comment: after changing environmet - u have to restrt ur project